# two way data binding horrors with angular 4 md-select

Tags: angular

I am coming from a react background with one way data flow and I need to do a bit of maintenance work on an angular 4 app. Upgrading would be too big a task for what I have to do.

I have a form and it gets updated from an api call which passes an object into a setter with an @input attribute:

```
export class UserFormComponent {
  @ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;

  @Input()
  set person(u: User) {
    this.userModel = {...u};

    this.form.reset(this.userModel);
  }
```

I then have an `md-select`:

```
<h1>{{ personModel.roleID }}</h1>
<h1>{{ personModel.email }}</h1>
<div class="mat-input-wrapper">
  <label for="roleID">Role</label>
  <md-select
    id="roleID"
    name="roleID"
    [(ngModel)]="personModel.roleID"
    class="md-input-container"
    required
  >
    <md-option *ngFor="let role of (roles | async)" [value]="role.id">
      {{ role.id }} - {{ role.name }}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

The `md-select` has a two way databinding on the `ngModel`, the problem is that the  `personModel` object is coming from an async api call and the way the original dev wrote was to pass is that an empty object will be passed to the setter:

```
  @Input()
  set person(u: User) {
    this.userModel = {...u};

    this.form.reset(this.userModel);
  }
```

When this happens, "personModel.roleID`is undefined and it looks the two way databinding on the`ngModel`of the`md-select` sets it to undefined on the model.

When the async call completes correctly, the full `personModel` will have the `roleID` but `md-select` looks like it does not pick up the change and it is still undefined on the model.

The same thing does not happen for an `input` declared like this:

```
 <input
    id="firstname"
    name="firstname"
    type="text"
    mdInput
    placeholder="First Name"
    required
    pattern="\s*(\S\s*){1,}"
    [(ngModel)]="personModel.firstname"
    #firstname="ngModel"
  />
```

THe 2 way databinding seems to work correctly even if `personModel.firstName` turns from undefined to its real value.

I thought 2 way databinding was discouraged in angular 2+ but is seems to be alive and kicking here.

Anybody know why this happens for the `md-select` and is it possible to use a one way data flow with angular 2+?.

Comment: Do you replace the object reference on `personModel` / just update the properties when your async call is completed?

Comment: they both seem pretty horrible ways.  i thought 2 way data binding had gone after angular 1